# Is there a way for a thread to listen to multiple BlockingQueues in Java?

Tags: java, multiplexing

In Java, is there a way for a thread to listen to multiple `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`? Just like `java.nio.channels.Selector` listen to multiple `java.nio.channels.SocketChannel`.

Comment: Did you check the example in the JavaDoc of `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`?

Comment: Why do you need to have multiple `BlockingQueue`s and listen to them from one thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you come across a situation like this, I would recommend you to first think about why you need to listen to multiple `BlockingQueue`s. If possible, try inserting to the same `BlockingQueue` in all of the producer tasks. This should be applicable if all consumer tasks are want to listen to all of the queues.

---

You can create another (master) `BlockingQueue` that gets entries from all other `BlockingQueue` and one Thread for each `BlockingQueue` you want to listen to that moves data to the master `BlockingQueue`:

```java
//data
private BlockingQueue<T> masterQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<T>(1);
private List<BlockingQueue<T>> toListenFrom = new ArrayList<>();//assume that has elements

private ExecutorService queueDistributorExecutor = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor();//use virtual threads if they are available - if not, use a different executor
```

```java
// distribute elements
for(BlockingQueue queue : toListenFrom){
    queueDistributorExecutor.execute(()->{
        try {
            while(true) {
                masterQueue.put(queue.take());
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    });
}
```

Then, you can read from all queues by reading from `masterQueue`.

This code makes the assumptions that it's no problem if elements from `toListenFrom` queues are removed for `masterQueue` even if `masterQueue` is full (these will be inserted later).
Due to that, my implementation is not "fair". The threads reading from the `masterQueue` would "reserve" one element from each other queue.

Comment: This code blocks on both `take()` and `put()`, so the situation you describe in your last paragraph cannot arise.

Comment: @user207421 While blocking on `put()`, the element is removed from the `toListenFrom` queue but not (yet) inserted i `masterQueue`.

Comment: Thanks, the reason why I need to listen to multiple `BlockQueue`s instead of one is that I need to listen to part of them dynamically. I think the second method is helpful, thanks again.